# Unlocking SQL Compact (.SDF) file when data entry form closes

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile-6.5

I have developed a small Stock-Take application that runs on a Windows Mobile 6.5 handheld device & uses a SQL Compact 3.5 (.SDF) data file.  I built the application in Visual Studio 2008 using VB.Net and it all works fine up to the point where I need to copy the data file back to the connected PC for further processing. When I close the application data entry form, the data file remains locked and I can't copy it to the PC.  In the Form_Closed event, I am issuing Dispose commands for both the TableAdapter and BindingSource, and have also added a Garbage Collect command, see code below, but the data file remains locked.

```
Private Sub StockCheckForm_Closed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closed
    Me.StockCheckTableAdapter.Dispose()
    Me.StockCheckBindingSource.Dispose()
    GC.Collect()
    MsgBox("Form Closed", , "Stock Check")
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like maybe the connection is still open. Either it's because it's still open explicitly, or open due to connection pooling. It looks like you're using typed datasets/adaptors so I'm not sure how to go about checking for that. I'm pretty sure there is a connection property in the adaptor there somewhere... try explicitly closing it before you dispose of it. It should be closing automatically, but I'm not sure. Typed datasets weren't something I used a lot of. It's also possible that connection pooling could be at play here. If that's the case, then ugh, I'm not sure what can be done.

Comment: I had an uncle Andrew Wilson, founder of the family business. Anyway to the subject at hand; I have avoided TableAdapters and there generated code but things do eventually time out and connections will eventually close on there own. Perhaps waiting a bit before attempting to copy the file might work.